# Jquery onchange Post

Tags: jquery

Hello  i want in the moment i select a value to post to the process.php page .
I have this code:

```
<select name="sweets" id="sweets" >
<option value="1">Chocolate</option>


<option value="2">Taffy</option>

<option value="3">Fudge</option>
<option value="4">Cookie</option>
```

and jquery:

```
 $("#sweets").change(function () {
      var str = "";
      $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).val() + " ";
         var q =  $(this).val();
          var dataString = 'q=' + q; 

           });
      $("div").text(str);
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "process.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function() {
                                         $('#form').slideUp('slow');
                                        }
                })

    })

    .change();
```

and i can't make it post the value to process.php.

Any help is appreciated,

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring `dataString` in an odd spot, but you can get the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) of the `<select>` directly much easier, like this:

```
$("#sweets").change(function () {
  $("div").text($(this).val());
  $.post("process.php", { q: $(this).val() }, function() {
    $('#form').slideUp('slow');
  });
}).change();
```

In the above I also converted your code to use [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) just as a shortcut, but it has the same effect.

Comment: Thank you Nick , i run your example on local and looking with Fireboog doesn't seem to post .. could you take a better look .. i'm begginer with Jquery thank you

Comment: @Teodor - are you running this inside a `ready` handler, e.g. all of the above wrapped in `$(function() { /* code */ });`?

Comment: Actually i put the file online to show you and online seems to work in both cases with and without document ready :) thank you .. something strange on local :)

Comment: Nick i added the example at : http://tourscript.com/test/test_sort2.html now my problem is: i already post this on the process page but how i gater back the result of the process page?

Comment: i wanted to do something like http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp but in jquery

Comment: i will post another question .. maybe in the final i will understand how to combine them